# Intoeing in older children

Tags: pediatrics, orthopedics, podiatry, toe, intoeing-pigeon-toe-foot

All of the information I have found online concerning intoeing (pigeon footedness) only concerns intoeing in younger children.

I have a friend who has a 9-year-old child who is displaying increasing intoeing and it was first noticed when the child was 8-years-old.

What treatments are there, if any for intoeing in children **OLDER THAN 8 YEARS**?